# Array of Char pointers (strings) crashes after input?

Tags: c, arrays, string, gets

I want to store an array of strings , count their length and re-arrange them with length-increasing-order (smallest->larger) using the algorithm mentioned below //
Swap holds a relatively big string to replace the order (when another min is found)
I could use realloc() but I am not considering defend programming yet

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



int main()
    {
        int i,j,N;
        printf("\n Input amount of alphanumericals: ");
        scanf("%d",&N);
            {
                int min;
                char *swap=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*150);
                char *A[N],**temp;
                temp=A;
                for(i=0;i<N;i++){
                    printf("\nInput %d element:",i+1); 
                    fgets(temp+i,150,STDIN);
                }


    printf("\n\nData [");
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        printf(" %s",A[i]);
    printf(" ]\n\n");

    //Ins sort
    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        min=i;//Assume current is min
        for(j=i+1;j<N;j++){
            //Compare assuming min with current
            if(strcmp(A[j],A[min])<0){
                min=j;
            }
            //If next is min replace in current position
        if(min!=i){
            swap=A[i];
            A[i]=A[min];
            A[min]=swap;
        }   
    }
    free(swap);
    printf("\nAfter insertion point algorithm\n");
    printf("\n\nInsertion Sorted Data [");
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        printf(" %s",A[i]);
    printf(" ]");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does it even compiled for you(gets(temp+i);)? Anyway you are declaring pointers here and using it without allocating memory

char *A[N],**temp;  temp=A;

Comment: Besides temp which is just a shortcut for doing gets(A+i) or store alphanumericals in all cell , yeah blcc is pretty elastic sometimes :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are tying to free memory that has not been allocated using `malloc`:

```
char *A[N],**temp;
temp = A;   // A is an automatic (AKA "stack") variable; now temp points to it as well
free(temp); // Undefined behavior
```

Inside the loop you are reading with `gets` into strings that have not been allocated:

```
gets(temp+i); // That's the same as gets(A[i]); Your A[i]s are unallocated.
```

As a side note, you should not use `gets`, because it is a prime source of buffer overruns. Use `fgets` instead, and pass `stdin` as the `FILE*` parameter. `scanf` with `%20s` is another alternative to limit the size.

In addition, since `i` goes from `1` to `N`, inclusive, this expression references one element past the `A` array on the last iteration:

```
gets(temp+i); // Undefined behavior when i==N
```

**EDIT :** Why is the code below crashes?

```
for(i=0;i<N;i++){
    printf("\nInput %d element:",i+1); 
    fgets(temp+i,150,STDIN);
}
```

The code below crashes because you did not allocate memory for the individual strings:

```
for(i=0;i<N;i++){
    printf("\nInput %d element:",i+1);
    temp+i = malloc(151); // No need to multiply by sizeof(char) or cast to char*
    fgets(temp+i,150,STDIN);
}
```

Note that you need to allocate one extra `char` for the null terminator.

Comment: It outputs:Input 1 element:<br/>
           Input 2 element:<I can type here><br/>
           Input 3 element:<here too><br/>
Then crashes

Comment: @niCk That is because it's undefined behavior: it may not crash for two or three times. It may even run to completion. However, such program may crash the next time you run it. If you would like to see a report of your memory errors, run [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).

Comment: edited to fgets() to avoid buffer errors but could you explain me why its still crashes I think I did legit allocations and assignements

Answer (score 0):

You are not using `gets` correctly: take a look at its manual page [1]. Moreover, using `gets` is not recommended: better use `fgets`.

Also, `gets` is not allocating the string for you, so when you pass it a `char *` pointer, the pointer has to point to a valid memory location. Instead, your `A[n]` is an array of dangling pointers.

Then, why `free(temp)`? You must call `free` for each pointer allocated with `malloc`: not the case for `temp`.

Finally, please format your code: use `indent`.

[1] http://linux.die.net/man/3/gets

Comment: I did use indent the format became crappy when I copy-code-paste certain parts , thanks for the documentation

Comment: @niCk - Once you paste formatted code from your editor into the edit box here, Select your newly pasted code, then click the _{}_ tool above the editor.  If your code was formatted correctly when pasted, this will help it to be formatted here as well.